# Как вывести слова из списка, содержащие в себе конкретную букву? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

При работе с файлом возникла необходимость вывести все слова из файла, содержащие в себе букву "с". Мой приложенный код выводит букву "i" столько раз сколько эти слова встретились ей в переборе.
Как вывести слова с заданным параметром? В чем моя ошибка?

Буду рад любым полезным комментариям

```
fin = open('words.txt', 'r+')
read = fin.readlines()
read_str = ''.join(read)
splited = read_str.strip()
for i in splited:
    if i == 'с':
        print(i)
fin.close()
```

Comment: Ну я бы разбил бы на слова и искал бы вхождения искомой буквы если есть попадание выводил слово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем случае Вы перепутали функцию `str.split()` с функцией `str.strip()`, и после начинаете побуквенно перебирать единую строку. Дальше, когда Вы находите букву в слове, то Вы выводите букву. Надо искать слово, которое включает букву. Еще хорошо бы приводить все слова к строчным, иначе заглавные буквы будут пропущены.

Немного причесал Ваш код:

```
letter = 'a'
with open('words.txt') as file:
    read = file.readlines()
    read_str = ''.join(read).lower()
    splited = read_str.split()
    for i in splited:
        if letter in i:
            print(i)
```

Его же можно сделать чуть более читаемым

```
letter = 'a'
with open('words.txt') as file:
    text = ' '.join(file.readlines()).lower().split(' ')  # Предположим, что слова идут через пробел и разбиты на строки
    filtered = [word for word in text if letter in word]
print(*filtered, sep='\n')
```

Еще вариант, чтобы лишний раз текст не бить, можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

letter = 'A'
with open('words.txt') as file:
    words = re.findall(
        f'[\s\W]*(\w*{letter}\w*)[\s\W]*', file.read(), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы усложняете себе жизнь:

1. Вместо пары команд

   ```
   fin = open(...)
   fin.close()
   ```

   лучше использовать так называемый *контекст менеджер* (команду `with`), который *автоматическим закрывает файл после выхода из него:*

   ```
   with open('words.txt') as fin:
       # Работа с файлом
       #   ...

   # Файл автоматически закрыт
   ```

   Этот подход имеет и другие преимущества — см. например объяснение 1 после моего решения ниже.
2. Вместо пары команд

   ```
   read = fin.readlines()
   read_str = ''.join(read)
   ```

   вы могли просто применить метод `.read()`:

   ```
   read_str = fin.read()
   ```

   который читает весь файл сразу.
3. Здесь ошибка:

   ```
   splited = read_str.strip()
   ```

   Вы наверно хотели применить метод `.split()` вместо `.strip()`:

   ```
   splited = read_str.split()
   ```

4. Здесь также ошибки:

   ```
   for i in splited:
       if i == 'с':
           print(i)
   ```

   - `print(i)` выводит то, что находится в переменной `i`, а в переменной `i` - выполняя условие `i == 'с'` - находится буква `c`.
   - Предполагая, что в переменной `i` находится слово (а не символ — см. предыдущий пункт 3), нужно тестировать не на равенство (`==`), а на *вхождение* (`in`):*

     ```
     for i in splited:
         if 'с' in i:
             print(i)
     ```
   - Имя переменной может помочь, но и запутать:

     - Что такое `i`? Слово? Так почему не назвать его `word`?
     - Что такое `splitted`? Список слов? Так почему не назвать его `words`?

       ```
       for word in words:
           if 'с' in word:
               print(word)
       ```

---

Я бы решил вашу задачу так:

```
LETTER = "c"
SYMBOLS = tuple(",;:.?!")
FILENAME = "words.txt"

with open(FILENAME) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        for word in line.split():
            if LETTER in word:
                if word.endswith(SYMBOLS):
                   word = word[:-1]
                print(word)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. `fin` представляет собой итеративный объект по строкам файла, потому его возможно использовать прямо в цикле `for`.
2. После применения метода `.split()` должно уничтожить возможную пунктуацию (точку, запятую, и тд.) из конца слова:

   ```
               if word.endswith(SYMBOLS):
                  word = word[:-1]
   ```
3. Метод `.endswith()` принимает как параметр *не только строку*, но и **кортеж строк**.

   Я создал такой кортеж из символов пунктуации — применением функции `tuple()` на строку из этих символов (которая рассматривается как итеративный объект по ее индивидуальных символах).

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = open('words.txt', 'r+')
read = fin.readlines()

read_str = ''.join(read)

splited = read_str.split()

df = []
for i in splited:
    for ind in i:
        
        if ind =='a':
            if i not in df:
                df.append(i)

print(df)
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('words.txt') as file:
    words = file.readline().split()
    for word in words:
        if "c" in word:
            print(word)
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы где-то кавычку забыли

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]